# How to get versions.php file as object from the wp-includes folder?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to get the **versions.php** file as an object from the WordPress wp-includes folder so I can get the modified date from it. I have however no clue on how to properly obtaining it.

This is some code I tried, I heard from others that this is to access pages and not meant to be used for files, I just get an error that it was not able to get the UNIX Timestamp of that file.

```
function getLatestUpdateDate() {
    $lastModifiedDate = date('Y-m-d', filemtime(includes_url('version.php')));
    return new WP_REST_Response($lastModifiedDate, 200);
}
```

I have also tried treating it like a normal file system. without any succes.

```
$lastModifiedDate = date('Y-m-d', filemtime("../../../wp-includes/version.php"));
```

The code above also sadly did not work, Anyone knows how to access these files?

Comment: This should not be using `includes_url` - you want to check something in the local file system. You can't even use `filemtime` with HTTP URLs to begin with, that's not supported.

Comment: `$filepath = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/version.php';` and then `$lastWritten = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filepath));`

Comment: The solution from @GrafiCode worked perfectly, I did not know there was a way to target the absolute path and target the includes folder. thank you!